# Black blank screen when using google chrome

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome

I've Dell Inspiron 1525 with Kubuntu 14.04. Recently when I checked for update Muon 
Update Manager told me that few updates are avilable so I updated it but now when I use Google Chrome for some time screen black and blank; and wouldn't work again until and unless I restart the comuter.[image: Blank Screen]